# Unable to fetch all company updates from LinkedIn using R

Tags: r, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch as many LinkedIn updates as possible for a company--

Here is the link I am using -

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/21837/updates?event-type=status-update&count=250

But it only returns 10 updates. There are many more updates but they don't show up in the response. All posts older than a month ago don't show up. Is there a limitation on how far back you can go?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: This seems to be a common issue (look at the Related sidebar...) with the LinkedIn API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 days seems to be the limit, according to the [LinkedIn API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares).

> Note that the API returns the latest 50 updates only for event type
>   status-update. If you have updates of other types (such as jobs
>   posting, product-updates etc.) then it can fetch up to 250 updates or
>   updates in the last 20 days whichever comes first.

The wording there isn't totally clear, their API documentation isn't very good unfortunately.